# How do I skip a few iterations in a for loop

Tags: python, loops

In python I usually loop through ranges simply by

```
for i in range(100): 
    #do something
```

but now I want to skip a few steps in the loop. More specifically, I want something like `continue(10)` so that it would skip the whole loop and increase the counter by 10. If I were using a for loop in C I'd just sum 10 to `i`, but in Python that doesn't really work.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You cannot alter the target list (`i` in this case) of a `for` loop. Use a `while` loop instead:

```
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    if i == 2:
        i += 3
```

Alternatively, use an iterable and increment that:

```
from itertools import islice

numbers = iter(range(10))
for i in numbers:
    if i == 2:
        next(islice(numbers, 3, 3), None)  # consume 3
```

By assigning the result of `iter()` to a local variable, we can advance the loop sequence inside the loop using standard iteration tools (`next()`, or here, a shortened version of the `itertools` consume recipe). `for` normally calls `iter()` for us when looping over a iterator.

Comment: I figured that might be the case, while loops are just sad though.

Comment: Ended up going with the while loop anyhow! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @AlexS If you are iterating over numbers, that's fine - if you are using those numbers as indices for lists or whatever, please don't do that. Iterating by index is bad in every way.

Answer (score 26):

The best way is to assign the iterator a name - it is common have an iterable as opposed to an iterator (the difference being an iterable - for example a list - starts from the beginning each time you iterate over it). In this case, just use [the `iter()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#iter):

```
numbers = iter(range(100))
```

Then you can advance it inside the loop using the name. The best way to do this is with [the `itertools` `consume()` recipe](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) - as it is fast (it uses `itertools` functions to ensure the iteration happens in low-level code, making the process of consuming the values very fast, and avoids using up memory by storing the consumed values):

```
from itertools import islice
import collections

def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

By doing this, you can do something like:

```
numbers = iter(range(100))
for i in numbers: 
    ...
    if some_check(i):
        consume(numbers, 3)  # Skip 3 ahead.
```

Comment: Note that even in Python 3, you *have* to call `iter()` on `range()` for this to work. The Python 3 `range()` object is a sequence (an iterable), not an iterator.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Incredibly good point. Edited. I iterate over ranges so little I forgot that was the case.

Comment: +1, this is seemingly the fastest way, and not too complicated.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just set the value to skip until?  Like:

```
skip_until = 0
for i in range(100):
    if i < skip_until:
        continue
    if SOME_CONDITION:
        skip_until = i + 10
    DO_SOMETHING()
```

where SOME_CONDITION is whatever causes you to skip and DO_SOMETHING() is the actual loop contents?

Comment: It's worth noting that this requires the loop to be executed in Python, and the name assigned each time - while it's not likely to be a problem in most cases, it is far less efficient in that sense.

Comment: Yeah, but given the simplicity of the question I figured he wanted a simple answer; messing with iterators seems like overkill if the loops/skips are small.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(0, 100, 10):
    print(i)
```

will print 0, 10, 20 ...

Comment: Hi, although this skips the first 10 values I think the asker was more interested in knowing how to skip ahead to an arbitrary value while **in the loop**.  See the top answer for an example.

Comment: You definitely don't need python 3.3 for this, either.

Answer (score 0):

Something that I keep using. You can use below to get a 10% prob on running your code:

```
import random
for i in range(1000000):
    if random.random() > 0.1:
        continue:
    # your code
```

Answer (score -2):

A charmed and simplest form is like that:

```
>>> for i in range(5,10):
...     print (i)
... 
5
6
7
8
9
```

Where `5` was the index that started iteration.