# How to change object once in a loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I am trying to make it so the object X is the background and A is an object to be moved up or down, but once i use loop to change the A to X, the loop finds the a in the next line and does it once again, how do i make it so it only changes once and moves on?

```
newlist = ['X','X','A','X','X','X','X']

for i in range(len(newlist)):

    print(newlist[i])

    if newlist[i] == 'A':

        newlist[i] = 'X'

        newlist[i+1] = 'A'
```

It should show

```
X
X
X
A
X
X
X
```

from

```
X
X
A
X
X
X
X
```

but right now it shows

```
X
X
X
A
A
A
A
```

Comment: What's the output for `newlist = ['X','X','X','X','X','X','A']`

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).  I mean, if the only thing important about `'A'` is its position, why not scrap the list and use an int to represent its position?

Comment: That output's not right. I just ran the code and got 2 X's and 5 A's, then an IndexError.

Answer (score 1):

While doing the downshift as well (just for myself) I found an even better approach than in my previous answer:

[deque](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) adds rotation functionality to iterables.

```
from collections import deque

newlist = ['X', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'A']
print(f'Original:\n{newlist}')  # debug

a = deque(newlist)
b = deque(newlist)

a.rotate(1)
newlist = list(a)
print(f'Shift up:\n{newlist}')

b.rotate(-1)
newlist = list(b)
print(f'Shift down:\n{newlist}')
```

**Result:**

```
Original:
['X', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'A']
Shift up:
['A', 'X', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'A', 'X']
Shift down:
['X', 'A', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'A', 'X']
```

Comment: Good choice. `deque` does this efficiently by using dynamic index windows of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

just use the command **break** after doing the change:

```
newlist = ['X','X','A','X','X','X','X']

for i in range(len(newlist)):

    if newlist[i] == 'A':

        newlist[i] = 'X'

        newlist[i+1] = 'A'

        break
print " ". join(newlist)
```

or with **continue**:

```
newlist = ['X','X','A','X','X','X','X']
k = -1
for i in range(len(newlist)):

    if k == i:
        continue

    if newlist[i] == 'A':

        newlist[i] = 'X'

        newlist[i+1] = 'A'

        k = i+1
print " ". join(newlist)
```

Comment: What if `newlist = ['X','X','A','X','A','X','X']`?

Comment: then use the command **continue** instead for the next value.

Answer (score 0):

The code is self-explanatory. There is an `if` case to check the existence of `[index+1]`

```
list = ['X','X','A','X','X','X','X']

try:
    for el in list:
        print(list)
        if el == 'A':
            index = list.index(el)
            if list[index+1]:
                list[index+1] = el 
            list[index] = 'X'
except:
    print('Out of index!!')
```

**Result:**

```
C:\Desktop>python test.py
['X', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'A', 'X']
['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'A']
Out of index!!
```

Comment: Never name a variable using ```list``` which is a built in type. Also, instead of calling ```.index``` - use ```for i, el in enumerate(ls)```

Answer (score 0):

With [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [next()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) you can manipulate the iterable. 
Kudos to my source: [How do I skip a few iterations in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17837346/11815313).

Also handled an 'A' at the very end and works with several 'A' in the list.

```
from itertools import islice

newlist = ['X', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'A']
print(newlist)  # debug

numbers = iter(range(len(newlist)))

for i in numbers:
    if newlist[i] == 'X':
        print(newlist[i])

    if newlist[i] == 'A':
        newlist[i] = 'X'
        print(newlist[i])
        if i < len(newlist) - 2:
            newlist[i+1] = 'A'
            print(newlist[i+1])
        next(islice(numbers, 1, 1), None)

print(newlist)  # debug
```

**Result:**

```
['X', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'A']
X
X
X
A
X
A
X
['X', 'X', 'X', 'A', 'X', 'A', 'X']
```

Answer (score 0):

In mixing the state output and state change operations, you've presented only one item of the list for each row. This is akin to using a super high frame rate without vertical blank synchronisation. Every row shows only a fraction of the whole picture, in this case the moment when the A appears in every position from its origin down. You could easily visualise this by printing `newlist` instead of `newlist[i]`.

The operation to move the A has several issues in itself. It's in a loop that we could assume is meant to find the A, but that's more efficiently done with the `index` method. More significantly, once found, you keep looping and therefore will continue moving the A until it hits the end - in this case with an `IndexError`, as there will be no `newlist[i+1]` entry to swap with. The traditional way to ensure the task is done once is to `break` out of a search loop. Another solution may be to never alter the list you're iterating over, but create a new generation derived from it; then you'll never read a newly modified position.

Yet another approach here works on the basis that X is the background and all As move in the same direction, including off the end of the list:

```
newstate = ['X']+oldstate[:-1]    # Shift to higher indices
```

And here is one where As move only if they can, based on a rule table:

```
moves = {('X', 'A', 'X'): 'X',  # Moved off to the right
         ('A', 'A', 'X'): 'X',  # Moved off to the right
         ('A', 'X', 'X'): 'A',  # Moved in from the left
         ('A', 'X', 'A'): 'A',  # Moved in from the left
        }
newstate = [moves.get((l,h,r), h) for (l,h,r) in 
            zip(['X']+oldstate, oldstate, oldstate[1:]+['A'])]
```

This uses an X as the left boundary and A as the right boundary to avoid As walking off the edges. It might be useful to define another cell state to represent a wall. On that note, this is an example of a cellular automaton.